# Check if a file (passed as an argument to a script) is of .iso type

Tags: command-line, scripts, iso

I'm working on a script that takes 2 arguments. The first is the path to a iso file and the second is the iso name. How can I check if the file is .iso type and not a different type of file?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'd recommend you take a look at our [tour] to get an idea of how to best use Ask Ubuntu. Furthermore, please read [ask] and [answer] to get some awesome helpful tips to get started writing and answering questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command:

```
% file ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso 
ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data (DOS/MBR boot sector) 'Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64' (bootable); partition 2 : ID=0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 14432, 4864 sectors
```

Take a look specifically at the `--mime-type` and `--brief` (`-b`) flags:

```
% file -b --mime-type ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
application/x-iso9660-image
```

You can then use [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) or similar to parse the output of the `file` command, and then read the status code:

```
% file -b --mime-type ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso | grep -q iso; echo $?
0
% file -b --mime-type wolf1.png | grep -q iso; echo $?
1
```

If you want to use this in a script (where `$1` is the passed in file, note [the lack of brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22728/56507)):

```shell
#!/bin/bash

if file -b --mime-type $1 | grep -q iso; then
    echo "Is ISO"
else
    echo "Is not ISO"
fi
```

Example:

```
% ./x.sh ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
Is ISO
% ./x.sh wolf1.png 
Is not ISO
```

Comment: I don't know how to use the result. I want if my file isn't iso to show a message..

Comment: You can use an [if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675681/bash-how-to-check-the-exit-status-using-an-if-statement) for that. Use `echo` to send a message and then exit with a non-zero status code.

Comment: I used an if, like this one : if [ file -b --mime-type $1 | grep -q iso == 1] echo"isn't iso"; exit 2. But it dosent work

Comment: Has to be `if [ $(file -b --mime-type wolf1.png | grep -q iso) -eq 1 ]; then echo "isn't iso"; exit 2; fi`

Comment: @derHugo No, it should be `if file -b --mime-type wolf1.png | grep -q iso; then echo "is iso"; else echo "is not iso"; exit 2; fi`

Comment: Not all ISOs are detected properly by file. I have one ISO (that I tested it on) which returned `application/octet-stream`.